# Making Fieldset Collapsed on Load

Tags: jquery, html

I need to made all the Fieldset Collapsed when users see my page. So, to see its content i should click on the Fieldset title. For Example: Here i have created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MWYRb/) which allows to collapse a non collapsed Fieldset, here is the jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('legend').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.content').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

But How to make all this Fieldset collapsed? and to see whats inside the Fieldset people should click on the Fieldset title and then the the Fieldset will be collapse? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

Add a css rule

```
fieldset .content {
    display: none;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sS9qN/)

or using jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('fieldset .content').hide();
    $('legend').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('.content').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Ek5dU/)